# Why is this `pgbench` benchmark faster on postgresql 11 than on postgresql 14?

Tags: performance, benchmark

To check postgresql performance, I ran the following benchmark with varying postgresql versions and filesystems:

```bash
pgbench --initialize --scale=50 bench
# Run for 3 minutes
postgres pgbench --client=10 --jobs=2 --time=180 bench
```

##### System environment

- postgresql settings: `shared_buffers = 8 GiB (of 32 GiB total system RAM)`
- 2x 7200 RPM HDDs

##### Results

| Filesystem | TPS (postgresql 11.16) | TPS (postgresql 14.4) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| zfs compression=lz4 | 497.21 | 288.93 |
| zfs compression=lz4 recordsize=8K | 488.11 | 430.83 |
| ext4 | 492.01 | 480.66 |
| btrfs mirror compression=zstd | 193.65 | 187.4 |

Overall, pg 11 is faster than pg 14, especially on ZFS with the default 128K recordsize.

What's the explanation for this result?
Did `pgbench` change between versions? Or did postgres increase data robustness/crash resistance at the cost of performance?

Comment: Are the execution plans the same?

Comment: Hi + welcome to dba.se! I'm not trying to be smart, but does anyone run a **real** server on spinning rust these days? Have you tried doing tests on SSDs? I know that PostgreSQL keeps an eye on regressions - check [this](https://www.enterprisedb.com/blog/postgresql-tproc-c-benchmarks-postgresql-12-vs-postgresql-13-performance) out. Have you tried running HammerDB on the same setup? 3 minutes doens't seem to be a long time to run a benchmark - I know that many benchmarks take a while to fill buffers, other memory structures and whatnot, so I'd rerun my benchmarks for a couple of hours at least.

Comment: @ik_zelf: Yes. In all cases, I ran the benchmark commands on a fresh postgres instance with an initially empty data dir. All parameters that were varied between benchmarks are mentioned above.

Comment: @Vérace-СлаваУкраїні, thanks! I would love to repeat this benchmark with HammerDB. Can you guide me to an explicit usage example that would be appropriate in this context?

Comment: Well, I'd be interested in the performance of more conventional file systems (ext4 and xfs) - also, you don't mention your OS (+ version). So, to obtain a decent set of numbers for comparison I would run my benchmarks for 2hrs (from my previous link `"Note: for a proper TPC-C benchmark, the test must be run for a minimum of two hours."`).  I would run 11, 12, 13 & 14 x (ZFS, ext4, xfs). I would also try to compare HDDs and SSDs. Also, notice the numbers from my link - they vary **wildly** with no. of clients, you could vary this also.

Comment: I know it's quite a bit of work - but a single run for 3 mins with 10 clients doesn't really tell us much. Maybe ZFS takes longer to crank up and start to hum along? Database benchmarking is a subject fraught with difficulties - there are lies, damned lies, statistics and **then** there are database benchmarks. In fairness to you, you're not trying to compare PostgreSQL with MySQL, but rather different versions of PG! Another question is "Did you vary the `postgresql.conf` parameters from their defaults? I wouldn't even bother with an untuned instance - the defaults are normally set too small!

Comment: @ErikArvstedt different versions can have different optimizer settings and refinements. Comparing the plans can help to see why things go slower if the plans differ. If the plans are the same you can compare and search for settings to tune the database. First find differences.’